# Does XP_API deprecation announcement mean that sp_executesql will not be supported in the future?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, extended-events, extended-stored-procedure

I have setup an Extended Events session in SQL 2008 R2 to track the [deprecation_final_support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178053(v=sql.105).aspx) and [deprecation_announcement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186302(v=sql.105).aspx) events.  I noticed some "deprecation_announcement" events in my log with "feature" of "XP_API", which appear to all be SQL statements that use [`SP_EXECUTESQL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001(v=sql.105).aspx).

The event message says:

> Extended stored procedure API will be removed in a future version of
>   SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan
>   to modify applications that currently use it.

One example of the `sql_text` action from an event is:

```
exec sp_executesql N'DECLARE @c varbinary(128);SET @c=cast(@userName as varbinary(128));SET CONTEXT_INFO @c;', N'@userName varchar(128)', @userName = 'MYDOMAIN\myuser';
```

The `master.sys.SP_EXECUTESQL` proc is listed under "Databases > System Databases > master > Programmability > Extended Stored Procedures > System Extended Stored Procedures" in Object Explorer.

Does this mean that `sp_executesql` will not be supported in a future version of SQL Server?

Comment: I really doubt it. The deprecation announcement is likely just around the ones that are explicitly named `xp_*` - and even then I doubt all of those will ever be gone.

Answer (score 4):

The [Deprecated Database Engine Feature List for SQL Server 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-2017) shows `XP_API` as the "feature name" for a list of now-unsupported features.  The list of deprecated features consists of:

```
srv_alloc
srv_convert
srv_describe
srv_getbindtoken
srv_got_attention
srv_message_handler
srv_paramdata
srv_paraminfo
srv_paramlen
srv_parammaxlen
srv_paramname
srv_paramnumber
srv_paramset
srv_paramsetoutput
srv_paramstatus
srv_paramtype
srv_pfield
srv_pfieldex
srv_rpcdb
srv_rpcname
srv_rpcnumber
srv_rpcoptions
srv_rpcowner
srv_rpcparams
srv_senddone
srv_sendmsg
srv_sendrow
srv_setcoldata
srv_setcollen
srv_setutype
srv_willconvert
srv_wsendmsg
```

These items are all part of the [Extended Stored Procedure API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-stored-procedures-reference/data-types-extended-stored-procedure-api?view=sql-server-2017), which is deprecated.

The [documentation for `sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) makes no mention of it being deprecated.  Although that might be an error of ommission, it seems very unlikely that a core piece of functionality will be deprecated.  Imagine all the code world-wide that would need to be retrofitted.

The deprecation-related Extended Events items are likely flagging some internal use by sp_executesql of one or more of the `xp_api` items listed above.  Since sp_executesql is an extended stored procedure implemented in the Engine, Microsoft will either re-factor the sp_executesql code to avoid calls to those deprecated events, or will not deprecate them for internal use.

This question is tagged with SQL Server 2008 R2; if you run an Extended Events session in SQL Server 2017 looking at the `deprecation_announcement` and `deprecation_final_support` events, you don't see `sp_executesql` firing events.  To test that, I used this session definition:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [deprecated events] ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.deprecation_announcement
(
    ACTION (
        package0.event_sequence
        ,sqlserver.client_app_name
        ,sqlserver.database_name
        ,sqlserver.is_system,sqlserver.sql_text
        )
)
, ADD EVENT sqlserver.deprecation_final_support
    (
        ACTION
        (
            package0.event_sequence
            ,sqlserver.client_app_name
            ,sqlserver.database_name
            ,sqlserver.is_system
            ,sqlserver.sql_text
        )
    )
ADD TARGET package0.ring_buffer (SET max_memory=(10240))
WITH (STARTUP_STATE=OFF);
ALTER EVENT SESSION [deprecated events] ON SERVER STATE=START;
GO
```

Then ran this code, which uses `sp_executesql`:

```
DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(max);
SET @cmd = 'SELECT CurrentDate = GETDATE();';
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @cmd;
```

The ring buffer output for the `[deprecated events]` session shows no messages as a result of executing the code.  However, if you run this code, which contains `sp_helpremotelogin`, which *is* on the deprecated list, you do see items in the ring-buffer output:

```
EXEC sp_helpremotelogin @remoteserver = 'test', @remotename = NULL;
```